# Very slow initialization of Joomla when on remote database

Tags: database, installation, global-configuration, performance

Running Joomla 3.9.15. When I am using a remote database (still on the same local network though), I am facing massive slow downs on the "before preloadComponents" phase of Joomla init. The actual database queries though are fast (check the time for "database queries total")[image]

When I use a localhost database, everything is normal: 
[image]

- This is with all 3rd-party plugins and components disabled.
- Pinging from localhost to database-host is normal
- There are no WAF firewalls between localhost and database host as far as I know.
- I tried playing with the session configuration (changing from PHP, to database, to redis), with no effect whatsoever.

I don't know what else to check. Any ideas on how to make this work? It shouldn't delay that much for a database on the same network.